# Finding the coefficient of $x^{10}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

I'm doing my maths homework and can't do one of the questions on the binomial expansion. The question is:

a) Find the first four terms in the expansion of $(1-x^2)^8$

b) Hence find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion of $(1-2x)(1-x^2)^8$

I can do the first part of the question fine ($1-8x^2+28x^4-56x^6+...$) but am unsure how to do part (b). Can you help me?

Comment: @AlexR Ah. Sorry about that, my stupidity. Will correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a) actually wants the coefficients of $(x^2)^8 +\ldots + (x^2)^5$. Then b) should be straightforward noticing that all other terms can't contribute to the $x^{10}$.
Name $p(x) = (1-x^2)^8 = a_{16} x^{16} + a_{14} x^{14} + \ldots$ then
$$(1-2x)p(x) = p(x) - 2xp(x) = \ldots + a_{10} x^{10} - 2 xa_9 x^9 + \ldots = (a_{10} -2a_9) x^{10} + \text{rest}$$
Now note that $p(x)$ has no $x^9$ term, hence $a_9 = 0$ so b) is no more calculations, just working with a).

Comment: I thought this might be the case. I was going to multiply out with the $x^{10}$ but the word "hence" threw me. Thought I would check with people better at maths than me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion of $(1-2x)(1-x^2)^8$

$1\cdot$ the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the expansion of $(1-x^2)^8$

$-2\cdot$the coefficient of $x^9$ in the expansion of $(1-x^2)^8$

Clearly, $(1-x^2)^8$ does not have any odd power of $x$ in the binomial expansion

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}
\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{8}&=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{8}{8 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}x^{2k}
\end{align}
The first four terms are given by
\begin{align}
&{8 \choose 0}\pars{-1}^{0}x^{2\times 0}
+{8 \choose 1}\pars{-1}^{1}x^{2\times 1}+{8 \choose 2}\pars{-1}^{2}x^{2\times 2}
+{8 \choose 3}\pars{-1}^{3}x^{2\times 3}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large 1 - 8x^{2} + 28x^{4} - 56x^{6}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> \pars{1 - 2x}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{8}&
> =\pars{1 - 2x}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{8}{8 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}x^{2k}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{8}{8 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{x^{2k} - 2x^{2k + 1}}
> \end{align}
>   Clearly, the coefficient of $\ds{x^{10}}$ in the expansion of
>   $\ds{\pars{1 - 2x}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{8}}$ is given by
>   $$
> {8 \choose 5}\pars{-1}^{5}=\color{#66f}{\large -56}
> $$